Optimal bidding and the value of the game
I migrated from this post, where the problem is a bidding game between two players on the sum of two fair die. Specifically, Player 1 rolls one die and sees the outcome and so does Player 2. They don't see each other's rolls. The higher bidder wins the sum of the die minus what they bid and the loser gains nothing (players bid privately and equal bids result in no gains to both players). What puzzles me is that my approach yielded a zero value of the game and I'm looking for some intuitive explanation (or correction if wrong).
My attempt: If your roll is $r$, then bid $b(r)$ (that increases with $r$) to receive an expectation of
$$E(r) = \frac{r-1}{6} \left(r-b(r)\right) + \frac{1}{6} \frac{r(r-1)}{2}$$
where you receive the value of your roll $r$ minus your bid if you roll higher with probability $(r-1)/6$ and your competitor's roll if your roll is higher than theirs. Of course, this was calculated assuming that your opponent will follow the same bidding strategy, after all this is logical since the game is symmetric.
You want to choose a bidding function so that it extremizes the above expectation for all $r$ (at the equilibrium): take $\frac{d}{db} = \frac{\frac{d}{dr}}{\frac{db}{dr}}$, you will get the differential equation $$\frac{d}{dr}\left(2(r-1)b(r)\right) =6r-3 \to 2(r-1)b(r)= 3r^2-3r +c$$
so $b(r) = \frac{3r}{2}$ ($c=0$ by plugging $r=1$ above), now back to the expectation to find that $E(r)=0$ at the equilibrium.

What is the term $\dfrac{1}{6}r(r-1)/2$? If I didnt get wrong, bidder gets payoff $r-b$ if he wins the bid, and otherwise nothing, so $\mathbb{E}[X]=(r-1)(r-b)/6$

@AngaeMT the expected gains of rolling higher than your opponent: $\sum \frac{1}{6} i$ from $1$ to $r-1$.

Isnt the game the one who bid the highest win? So even the one has a higher rolling also get reward from it?

The winner gets the sum of the die not just his roll.

@ASA I recommend using inclusive pronouns (“not just their roll”). Defaulting to male pronouns is one of many ways that we exclude women and non-binary people from mathematical communities.

One of the major problem in your attempt is that even though you only want to investigate the symmetric BNE (each bidder uses the same strategy), you cannot assume it inside the objective function because you are deriving the possible relation between $b$ and the other bidder strategy (let's say $b_j$). The expected value should be only apply on the types of bidders (in this case, which is $r_j$, the dice thrown by bidder $j$), but not an expected guess on the strategy of other bidder.
More likely, if you assume it directly, then the bidder can win $$(r_i+r_j-b)$$
if $b_i(r_i)>b_j(r_j)$. By $b_i=b_j$ and increasing of $b_i$, we have this happening if $r_i>r_j$. This means it is a pure-luck game, instead of a bidding strategy. Thus, the optimal strategy will become $b\equiv0$, which is contradicting to monotonicity of $b$.

I suspected this was the case but I didn't assume that $b_i=b_j$, I only assumed that both strategies should be increasing with $r$ (maybe this also has to be reconsidered). Anyways, how do you think we can arrive at the closed form of $b$ then?

If you did not assume, then you cannot conclude the probability of bidder $i$ winning is $(r-1)/6$.

And more likely, note that the probability is still $\mathbb{P}[b_i(r_i)>b_j(r_j)]$ but monotonicity implies inverse exists and so we can make it $\mathbb{P}[b_j^{-1}(b_i(r_i))>r_j]=\dfrac{\lfloor{b_j^{-1}(b_i(r_i))}\rfloor}{6}$.  So the expected value without additional assumption on would be sth like $(r_i+\mathbb{E}[r_j]-b_i)\dfrac{\lfloor{b_j^{-1}(b_i(r_i))}\rfloor}{6}$. The idea is actually same as proving the Nash equilibrium of first price auction, but I do not know how to proceed further as well.

I guess the floor functions in my comment above can be dropped as $r_j$ must be integer (but im not sure, so i split another answer), if dropped, then the optimization problem is formed $$\min_{b_i}(r_i+\mathbb{E}[r_j]-b_i)\dfrac{{b_j^{-1}(b_i(r_i))}}{6}\iff \min_{b_i}(r_i+\mathbb{E}[r_j]-b_i){{b_j^{-1}(b_i(r_i))}}$$ Consider its FOC on $b_i$ gives $$(r_i+\mathbb{E}[r_j]-b_i)\dfrac{d}{db_i}[b_j^{-1}(b_i(r_i))]-b_j^{-1}(b_i(r_i))=(r_i+\mathbb{E}[r_j]-b_i)\dfrac{1}{b_j'(b_j^{-1}(b_i(r_i)))}-b_j^{-1}(b_i(r_i))=0$$
Note the derivative of the inverse part is obtained by inverse differentiation law. Rearranging gives $$\dfrac{(r_i+\mathbb{E}[r_j]-b_i)}{b_j'(b_j^{-1}(b_i(r_i)))}=b_j^{-1}(b_i(r_i))$$
At this moment, since we are searching for the symmetric BNE, we have $b_i(r_i)=b_j(r_i)$, and thus, rearranging gives $$\dfrac{(r_i+\mathbb{E}[r_j]-b_j(r_i))}{r_i}=b_j'(r_i)\iff (r_i)b_j'(r_i)+b_j(r_i)=r_i+\mathbb{E}[r_j]$$
This is a first order ODE. Integrating both sides we get $$r_ib_j(r_i)=\int^{r_i}_0x_i+\mathbb{E}[r_j]dx_i=\dfrac{r_i^2}{2}+r_i\mathbb{E}[r_j]$$
So $b_j(r_i)=b_i(r_i)=\dfrac{r_i}{2}+\mathbb{E}[r_j]$.

The approach I think is correct but when taking the FOC, the $E[r_j]$ is not independent of $b_i$ since essentially $E[r_j] = E[r_j | r_j < b_j^{-1} (b_i(r_i))]$.
